# Java TLS 1.2 server : AES-GCM decryption

Tags: java, aes, tls1.2, aes-gcm

I'm currently working on a Java TLS server. (I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274214/tls-1-2-ecdhe-rsa-signature) a few days ago regarding KeyExchange signature)

I'm now trying to decrypt TLS message encoded using AES-GCM. The server already handles CBC but since it's vulnerable to POODLE we'd like to do GCM instead. I'll try to explain as best as I can :)

For this code we are using Java 8u91, Netty 3.9.0. We do not use BouncyCastle and we don't intend to, we would like to stick with the JDK.

The code !

```
/**
 * Deciphers the fragment and returns the deciphered version of it
 * 
 * @param fragment
 *            to decrypt
 * @return the decrypted fragment
 * @throws InvalidKeyException
 * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
 * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
 * @throws BadPaddingException
 */
    private ChannelBuffer decodeCiphered(ChannelBuffer fragment, short contentType, byte[] version) throws InvalidKeyException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    if (readCipher != null) {
        byte[] ciphered = fragment.array();
        if (session.cipherSuite.cipher.type == CipherType.stream) {
            /* ... */
        } else if (session.cipherSuite.cipher.type == CipherType.block) {
            /* ... */
        } else if (session.cipherSuite.cipher.type == CipherType.aead) {
            byte[] nonce = concat(clientWriteIV.getIV(), fragment.copy(0, 8).array());
            // ClientWriteIV + explicit nonce (first 8 bytes of encrypted data)
            
            readCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clientWriteKey,
                new GCMParameterSpec(session.cipherSuite.cipher.block * 8, nonce));

            ChannelBuffer aad = ChannelBuffers.buffer(13);
            //seq_num(8B) + TLSCompressed.type(1B) + TLSCompressed.version(2B) + TLSCompressed.length(2B)

            aad.writeLong(writeSequence.longValue());
            aad.writeByte(contentType);
            aad.writeBytes(version);
            aad.writeShort(fragment.readableBytes() - 8 - 16);
            readCipher.updateAAD(aad.array());
            ciphered = readCipher.doFinal(ciphered, 8, ciphered.length - 8);
            fragment = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(ciphered);
        }
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Generates the different needed keys.
 */
private void generateKeys() {
    byte[] keyBlock = null;
    if (session.cipherSuite.cipher.type == CipherType.aead) {
        keyBlock = new byte[2 * session.cipherSuite.cipher.key
                    + 8];
        
        try {
            prf(keyBlock, session.masterSecret, KEY_EXPANSION_LABEL, concat(serverRandom, clientRandom));
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        }
        clientWriteKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBlock,0 , session.cipherSuite.cipher.key, session.cipherSuite.cipher.kalgo);
        serverWriteKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBlock, session.cipherSuite.cipher.key, session.cipherSuite.cipher.key, session.cipherSuite.cipher.kalgo);
        clientWriteIV = new IvParameterSpec(keyBlock, 2 * session.cipherSuite.cipher.key, 4);
        serverWriteIV = new IvParameterSpec(keyBlock, 2 * session.cipherSuite.cipher.key + 4, 4);
        
    } else {
        /* ... 
            For CBC
        */
    }
}
```

I am constantly getting the following error :

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:524)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1023)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:960)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2223)
at com.seemy.codec.tls.TlsCodec.decodeCiphered(TlsCodec.java:525)
```

It seems usually this means the AAD isn't right. But as far as I can tell from the [RFC 5246 Section 6.2.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.3) the AAD needs to be as follows :

```
The additional authenticated data, which we denote as additional_data, is defined as follows:

  additional_data = seq_num + TLSCompressed.type +
                    TLSCompressed.version + TLSCompressed.length;
where "+" denotes concatenation.
```

I'm at lost to find what I'm doing wrong to decrypt this message. The "Tag Mismatch" error isn't of much help to find what's wrong, so I hope someone here can help me :)

Thank you and have a nice day !

**Edit 1 :**
I was putting a short instead of a byte in contentVersion, however the result is still the same. I get only Tag Mismatch errors...

**Edit 2 :**
As suggested by @dave_thompson_085 `doFinal` is now called on `(ciphered, 8, ciphered.length-8)` instead of `(ciphered, 0, ciphered.length)` to exclude the explicit_nonce.

I also checked the aad and nonce values with more scrutiny.

The explicit_nonce part of the nonce corresponds to the packet I'm seeing in Wireshark. I am now worried the client_write_IV isn't properly generated :|

As for the aad I discovered something a bit weird : the length is 0.

The message I'm getting from the client is 40 Bytes long, minus 8 for the explicit_nonce part, minus the MAC length which is 32 for SHA-256(I'm trying to get tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_128_gcm_sha256 working).

Consequently if I try tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_256_gcm_sha384, the length ends up being -16. This seems wrong to me.

**Edit 3 :**
Again I did as @dave_thompson_085 suggested and modified my code to have the length as follow : `aad.writeShort(fragment.readableBytes() - 8 - 16);` whereas before I did `aad.writeShort(fragment.readableBytes()-8-session.cipherSuite.mac.len);`

It seems to work well when talking with chrome (even though it fails after when I send my own encrypted message but this will require another post later if I can't fix it by myself) but when trying with open_ssl client I get a Tag Mismatch again. Firefox & Safari just send me protocol_version alerts…

Comment: [Java 8 already supports TLS with AES and GCM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) - no need to implement it.

Comment: Yes, but the existing code I'm working on doesn't use the JSSE :/ And redoing it whole isn't really an option :)

Comment: Implementing TLS in Java will be pretty slow. Every Java implementation I know therefore uses native code. IMHO I would do it like Google - use OpenSSL/BoringSSL and a Java wrapper.

Comment: TLS is already implemented, only the GCM decryption/encryption part isn't. The server works fine in CBC :)

Comment: (1) CBC is vulnerable to POODLE only in SSLv3, or if you do padding wrong in TLS. You should no longer use SSLv3, nor do padding wrong in any version. CBC is vulnerable to BEAST through TLSv1.0; Duong&Rizzo achieved chosen initial plaintext only with zero-days that were quickly fixed, but there could be others. In all versions CBC is vulnerable to Lucky13 at least theoretically; that requires very repeatable timing and I haven't heard of it working outside the lab yet.

Comment: (2) tag-mismatch doesn't imply just AAD; the tag is computed over the AAD and ciphertext using the key and nonce and if any of those are wrong the tag fails. (That's the whole point of authenticated encryption with additional data.) Assuming the variables and methods not shown do what their names indicate, it looks right to me for GCM (not CCM or Chacha) EXCEPT you should decrypt the encrypted-record body EXCLUDING the explicit IV (but including the tag, because JCE does that), i.e. fragment from 8 to length.

Comment: Thank you very much @dave_thompson_085 ! I suspected that I could get the Tag Mismatch for other reasons than just the AAD being wrong but wasn't sure.

I'll look over all this and come back here with my findings :)

Comment: I tried it, there seems to be something else I'm doing wrong. I explained it in the post itself in "Edit 2". If there's something missing from my post (methods, variables that could be the source of the problem)  I'll gladly add anything relevant :)

Comment: (3) I don't know about `ChannelBuffer` but your code clearly puts 13 bytes, which look correct, into the instance `aad`, so if you're not getting those 13 bytes back out look at the doc (or source) for that. Or maybe just use `ByteArrayOutputStream`. (4) the tag length for GCM is always 16 bytes (128 bits), and is already removed by `Cipher.doFinal`; the hash named in the ciphersuite (SHA256 or SHA384) is irrelevant to AEAD record processing and should not be subtracted from anything. (It _should_ be used in PRF for key derivation and Finished, and only there.)

Comment: (3) I do get the 13 bytes back out of it, the thing is that the Short for the length ends up being 0. (4) the tag is removed by Cipher.doFinal but I still have to put "the length of my buffer - 8 - 16" as the length for the aad, don't I ?

Comment: Ah! I thought you meant the length OF the AAD, but you meant the length IN the AAD. Yes that is computed as encrypted_len minus explicitIV_len (8 for GCM) minus MAC_len (16 for GCM because the tag is the MAC). And now I think about it, if this is the _first_ record you are decrypting, it is just after CCS, and therefore is the Finished message, which is indeed 16 bytes (40 - 8 - 16).

Comment: Yes, I figured it out ;) I think my decryption is working now, I'm working on encryption and once I see that all is okay, I'll post an answer here !

Comment: Ok so it was a false positive. Safari, Safari Technology Preview, Firefox Developer Edition & openssl all end up with my server on a Tag Mismatch when decrypting. I don't understand why I can decrypt it with Chrome but heck I'd prefer supporting all the others especially when openssl s_client seems to be the preferred client to test servers :)